# browser shot laravel hidden footer and header when background is active

Tags: laravel, browsershot, spatie-browsershot

```
$pdf = Browsershot::url($url)
            ->waitUntilNetworkIdle()
            ->showBackground()
            ->showBrowserHeaderAndFooter()
            ->format('A4')
            ->fullPage()
            ->footerHtml(view('relatorio.components.footer')->render())
            ->headerHtml(view('relatorio.components.logo', $report)->render())
            ->pdf();
```

is it normal when you pass ->showBackground(), to cover the footer and header? i can show it by passing a transparency for the color but it looks wrong this way.